# IntelliJ quick fix for errors without placing the cursor under the highlighted area

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, jetbrains-ide

Is it possible to enable quick fix for errors anywhere in the line?

In the image below I opened quick fix (control+1, Eclipse KeyMap) while having the cursor **at the start of the line:** (`int` part)

[image]

What I want, is that if I have the cursor in the `int` part of the line, solution will be included in the quick fix list:

[image]

I tried to find a solution in the official IntelliJ but I was unable to find if there is any setting for this.

I put `Java` as tag because I am only trying to find the solution for the java editor of IntelliJ .

With other words I am looking to do what Eclipse does:

[image]

Comment: For future readers, if any, I opened request as @CrazyCoder suggested: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-290802

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Quick fixes are context sensitive and are suggested depending on where the caret is located. The quick fixes are different for different parts of the line and there is no option to provide all possible fixes for the current line. A feature request [is welcome](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA).